# Set focus of UITextField of firstViewController on secondViewController

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

How do I set a particular UITextField on my firstViewController to focus when my secondViewController pops from the navigationController?

Answer (score 1):

Write `[TexfieldName becomeFirstResponder];`  in ViewdidLoad in secondViewController.

This will  focus to particular textField and show keyboard.

Comment: I do not want to set focus to it when the view loads. But only when my secondViewController pops.

Comment: I can't do that, as it will affect other stuff. I only want it to particular set focus only when my secondViewController did pop. I mean, right before my secondViewController pops(firstViewController will be displayed), I need to set focus on a UITextField in FirstViewController.

Comment: [navigationController popViewController]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `viewWillAppear:`, you could make use of the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` method `– navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` and make invoke your method that way instead.

Just make sure some class is the `delegate` of you navigation controller, and get it to call a method in `firstViewController` invoking `becomeFirstResponder`.

EDIT: Link to the Apple documentation on [UINavigationControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).